# PostgreSQL can't update a column with content of another column

Tags: sql

checked several threads and some did help but now I'm getting an error:

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
>   SQL state: 21000

Not sure what's the exact issue even though read some explanations. Would appreciate if someone could explain with using my code bellow.

I have a table / view called `vw_inv_stock_art_global`, and it has a column "stock" with a number.

Then also I have a table dis_orderoutdetails with a column "onstock" which needs to copy the "stock" cells based on article_id both tables have in common.

```
UPDATE dis_orderoutdetails
SET onstock = (SELECT stock
        FROM vw_inv_stock_art_global
        WHERE vw_inv_stock_art_global.article_id = dis_orderoutdetails.article_id)
WHERE onstock is NULL
AND EXISTS(SELECT stock
        FROM vw_inv_stoc_art_global
        WHERE vw_inv_stock_art_global.article_id = dis_orderoutdetails.article_id);
```

Additional help if you can be bothered:
I was wondering if there's a possibility to change background colour of a cell just in SQL? Wanted to make an if...else and change colours of a cell depending on the result.

Comment: Tables have columns that have a data type, they are not "cells" that have a background color

Comment: You might be looking for `update dis_orderoutdetails set ... from  vw_inv_stoc_art_global where ...` instead. But without some more details (e.g. sample data) this is hard to answer.

Comment: @DWho . . . The error is pretty clear.  *You* need to figure out what to do when there are multiple rows returned by the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this part of the statement:

```
SET onstock = (SELECT stock
        FROM vw_inv_stock_art_global
        WHERE vw_inv_stock_art_global.article_id = dis_orderoutdetails.article_id)
```

The `SELECT` query returns more than one row => there are more than one row in the vw_inv_stock_art_global view that has this article_id. If the result of a `SELECT` is to be used as a value there may only be one matching row.

Not sure about Postgres SQL syntax but it seems you would use `LIMIT 1` to solve this.

```
SET onstock = (SELECT stock
            FROM vw_inv_stock_art_global
            WHERE vw_inv_stock_art_global.article_id = dis_orderoutdetails.article_id LIMIT 1)
```

*However* when you use LIMIT you probably need to use an `ORDER BY` clause as well to make sure that you use the most relevant row, not just any single row that matches the criterion. The most relevant row is most of the times the latest, so if there is some date column that specifies the entry of the row it is a good bet to be the column you need to order on. This is something you need to review according to your needs.

The ORDER BY would be inserted like this:
(Place holder  needs to be replaced)

```
SET onstock = (SELECT stock
            FROM vw_inv_stock_art_global
            WHERE vw_inv_stock_art_global.article_id = dis_orderoutdetails.article_id 
            ORDER BY <some column> 
            LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! Without order by, but I'll play around with it a bit more.

Comment: Great! As said, do consider the order by, it is a detail that is easy to forget when the query "just works". Forgetting may lead to updating with old data, which might - depending on database model - be an error which is hard to roll back.

Comment: If the answer is helpful it would be nice of you to upvote and marked as an answer

Comment: I did upvote it but it's not shown since I have less than 15 upvotes myself.
And just noticed the button to mark the answer as helpful (I think).

Comment: Thank you, the votes and answer points is whats keeps the contributions to this site rolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your SQL without using subqueries, like:

```
UPDATE dis_orderoutdetails
SET onstock = g.stock
FROM vw_inv_stock_art_global
WHERE vw_inv_stock_art_global.article_id = dis_orderoutdetails.article_id
      and onstock is NULL;
```

But be aware that the correctness of this SQL depends on the relationship between `dis_orderoutdetails(article_id)` and `vw_inv_stock_art_global(article_id)`: `article_id` isn't a unique column in `vw_inv_stock_art_global`, this `UPDATE` won't be predictable, as each `dis_orderoutdetails` could be updated more than once, with different stock values.